# How to disable Network and Bluetooth driver loading

Tags: boot, drivers

I dont need Bluetooth and Ethernet. SO I want that the next time I boot my system the OS do not waste time in loading corresponding drivers.

How do I do in general in any linux flavor ?

Comment: I don't think you will save significant amounts of time by skipping Linux modules/drivers.

Answer (score 1):

To stop bluetooth service

```
$ su -
$ service bluetooth stop
```

To disable bluetooth service on startup

```
# nano /etc/rc.local
```

add this line before exit 0

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

To disable the bluetooth driver on startup

```
# nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

source: [How to disable bluetooth on ubuntu, xubuntu and linux min](http://namhuy.net/1397/disable-bluetooth-ubuntu-xubuntu-linux-mint.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can blacklist those modules putting those modules in

> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist

as explained [here](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com.es/2009/06/how-to-disable-loading-of-unnecessary.html).

Comment: Do you expect this way I will get to the command prompt early as compared to without blacklisting?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can make your tests and post your results...

Comment: The link says, It will save memory, but I was wondering if it can save on time also- which is what I want.

Comment: You should put the relevant portion of the external link in your answer. As it is, if that page were to become unavailable, this answer would lose it's value.

Comment: The important part is what I posted, he needs to put the modules he doesn't want loaded inside that file. Regarding the time... I don't think loading those two modules would make a difference in time since their size is small. To gain time in the startup of the system you should use one of the systems (in case your distro is not using it) that launch parallel processes at startup like upstart or systemd. If you want to speed your startup you can also use an ssd drive (in case you haven't done that yet). You don't need a big one, I have one with 32GB just for the OS system starts like a rocket.